# SyntaxError: Unexpected token Q

Tags: javascript

Using this code in Chrome Console I get an error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token Q
```

What I need is to convert input in an object using JSON.parse().

Any idea how to fix this error?

```
var input = 'QR|BEGIN:VEVENT\r\nSUMMARY:Event test 18 APrile\r\nDTSTART:20130418T085900Z\r\nDTEND:20130418T105900Z\r\nLOCATION:Class 18\r\nDESCRIPTION:Desc 18 APrile\r\nEND:VEVENT';

    var output = input.split(/\r\n/);
    output = "{" + output  + "}";
    alert(output);

    var outputJson = JSON.parse(output);
    console.log(outputJson);
```

Comment: That's no JSON at all.

Comment: Your input string is missing much more than just `{}` to be valid JSON.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` is not creating JSON out of thin air like you probably expect, it rather just parse raw string formatted as JSON to actual object that can be used. It's expecting the string to be valid JSON, which in your case as others already mentioned, is not.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, if you post it as an answer I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's not [JSON](http://www.json.org/) at all, don't parse it as JSON. Here's how you can do it :

```
var obj = {};
input.split("\r\n").forEach(function(t){
  var nv = t.split(':');
  obj[nv[0]]=nv[1];
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ametaw/1/edit) (click "Run with JS" and open the console)

(note that this code needs [a shim due to forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to run on IE8)

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse needs a JSON format string as a parameter and converts it to a JavaScript object. Your variable `input` is not in JSON format, hence the error message.

You can refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON regarding what a JSON format string looks like and how it is built up.

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON.parse()` method is expecting valid JSON string to begin with.

Your real task here is to make such a valid string out of your existing data and one way is:

```
var output = input.split(/\r\n/);
for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    var temp = output[i].split(":");
    output[i] = "\"" + temp[0] + "\": \"" + temp[1] + "\"";
}
var strJSON = "{" + output.join(", ") + "}";
var outputJson = JSON.parse(strJSON);
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/V38aV/).

Comment: Why make this complex change and parse it as JSON when it's simpler to directly parse the string ?

Comment: @dystroy one single loop, not that complex. Just prefer to make minimal changes in the original request which in this case is using `JSON.parse()` for whatever reasons.